# Golang Command-Line String Flag

Tags: go

I'm trying to get command line flags working with strings in golang. Here is my main/main.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    flagString := flag.String("string", "foo", "Enter this string and have it printed back out.")

    log.Println("You entered ", *flagString)

 }
```

This simply takes the flag from the command line and prints it out, with default value "foo".

I enter the following into the command prompt after building the project, trying to make it print out bar:

```
> main -string=bar

(log time+date) You entered foo

> main -string="bar"

(log time+date) You entered foo
```

Is there something wrong with my code or am I entering it into the command prompt incorrectly?

By the way, I am running Windows 10.

Comment: You'll need to call `flag.Parse()` somewhere.

Comment: @svsd Thanks, I've answered it so that future readers can see.

Comment: you have to keep making good questions and answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

After calling flag.String(...), you need to simply call flag.Parse().

In your example:

package main

```
import (
     "flag"
     "log"
)

func main() {
     flagString := flag.String("string", "foo", "Enter this string and have it printed back out.")
     flags.Parse()

     log.Println("You entered ", *flagString)

}
```